# How to benchmark USB Accelerator coral beta by google?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I want to benchmark the USB Accelerator coral beta by google with use the function time.time() of Python.

I started by install Edge TPU runtime library. I found the procedure on [Google](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/accelerator/get-started/).

Then, I followed  then method to run inference with classification neuronal network.
I execute this commands lines:

```
     cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/demo

    python3 classify_image.py \
    --model ~/Downloads    /mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
--label ~/Downloads/inat_bird_labels.txt \
--image ~/Downloads/parrot.jpg
```

Now I want benchmark this example, so I  went to the classify_image.py and i implemented function time.time() of Python library for measure time of execution of the neuronal.

Here are the changes I have made:

```
   def main():
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument(
      '--model', help='File path of Tflite model.', required=True)
      parser.add_argument(
      '--label', help='File path of label file.', required=True)
      parser.add_argument(
      '--image', help='File path of the image to be recognized.', required=True)
      args = parser.parse_args()
      print ("[ INFO ] Loading network files:")
      print(args.model)
      print ("[ INFO ] Loading image file:")
      print(args.image)
      print ("[ INFO ] Starting inference (5 iterations)")
      print ("[ INFO ] Loading label file:")
      print (args.label)
      # Prepare labels.
      labels = ReadLabelFile(args.label)
      temps=0.0
      print("[ INFO ] stard profiling")
      print(".................................................")
      for i in range(4):
          # Initialize engine.
          engine = ClassificationEngine(args.model)
          # Run inference.
          print("[ INFO ] Loading image in the model")
          t1=time.time()           
          img = Image.open(args.image)
          result=engine.ClassifyWithImage(img, threshold=0.1, top_k=5, resample=0)
          t2=time.time()
          temps=temps+(t2-t1)

      print("[ INFO ] end profiling")
      print(".................................................")
      print("total inference time {} s:".format(temps))  
      print("Average running time of one iteration {} s:".format(temps/5.0)) 
      print("Throughput: {} FPS".format(5.0/temps*1.0))
```

The result is "Average running time of one iteration 0.41750078201293944 s".

```
[ INFO ] Loading network files:
inception_v1_224_quant.tflite
[ INFO ] Loading image file:
/cat_W_3000_H_2000.jpg
[ INFO ] Starting inference (5 iterations)
[ INFO ] Loading label file:
/imagenet_labels.txt
[ INFO ] stard profiling
.................................................
[ INFO ] end profiling
.................................................
total inference time 2.0875039100646973 s:
Average running time of one iteration 0.41750078201293944 s:
Throughput: 2.3952050944158647 FPS
```

When i wanted verifies if my results ares correct I went to this link [Google](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/benchmarks/) (official website for USB Accelerator coarl beta by google), and I found for neuronal network inception_v1 (224*224) they measure 3.6 ms, while I measure 417 ms.

So, my question is: how i can benchmark correctly the USB Accelerator coarl beta by google ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. First, to get "correct" benchmark numbers, you have to run several times (rather than just one). Why? Usually, it takes some extra time to prepare the running environment and there might be variance between runs. Second, the `engine.ClassifyWithImage` includes image processing time (scaling and cropping the input image). So, a "right way" to do it (1) add some warm-up runs and run multiple times, and (2) use `ClassificationEngine` instead of `ClassifyWithImage`. Actually, I did that about two month ago and put my code on github, see my [scripts here](https://github.com/freedomtan/edge_tpu_python_scripts).

Answer (score 0):

The latency numbers provided on Google's website are inference time, excluding image preparation time. The Python API returns the inference latency as part of the results as described [here](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/reference/edgetpu.classification.engine/#edgetpu.classification.engine.ClassificationEngine.RunInference). To measure wall time, you can time start and end of inference. You should also turn off cpu scaling before benchmarking.
[get_inference_time()](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/reference/edgetpu.classification.engine/#edgetpu.classification.engine.ClassificationEngine.get_inference_time) returns the inference time which is measured in milliseconds.